# Small amount of hardware reserved memory meaning?

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, 64-bit

I know there are a lot of questions about "hardware reserved memory", but almost all of them are regarding to fix high amount of reserved memory. I am wondering about the case where there is a low amount hardware reserved memory.

> [image: picture of hardware reserved memory from my computer]

For example, in my case there is 96mb of hardware reserved memory. So what's the reason for that and who might be using that memory. My OS is 64-bit Windows 10 and I have total amount of 32gb memory installed.

Comment: Low reserved memory is most likely just memory reserved for basic drivers: Display, mouse, keyboard and possibly WiFi and Bluetooth for example.

Comment: To expand on what @Giacomo1968 is saying.. devices often need a space to marshal data to and from the bus.  I don't think that it IS the drivers but memory needed BY the drivers as the drivers themselves are stored in kernel space.